# Use camera as background, while display objects in A-frame

Tags: three.js, aframe

I want to use camera video feed as background in a-frame, while overlaying  objects on it. I know it is possible but I don't know how exactly to do it.
so I am here to ask for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a simple overlay by adding an element before the scene:

```
<img src='overlay.jpg' />
<a-scene></a-scene>
```

fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nh1qfo26/1/).

---

[Here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) is a nice article about using a camera stream, I'll just use a basic version of it:

**html**

```
<video autoplay></video>
<a-scene></a-scene>
```

**js**

```
// grab the video element
const video = document.querySelector('video');
// this object needs to be an argument of getUserMedia
const constraints = {
   video: true
};
// when you grab the stream - display it on the <video> element
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).
    then((stream) => {video.srcObject = stream});
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dm0p6aes/).

Answer (score 0):

I took the above example and turned it into a glitch so the demo could be run on a phone. I also modified the aframe example code to look like a basketball game.

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/3dof-ar?path=index.html%3A33%3A33